# Copy Windows Graphics() image to clipboard C#

Tags: c#, windows, forms, graphics, clipboard

I have a windows form app written in C# (VS 2012, Windows 8) that does some custom drawing on a form using the graphics class.  I'm trying to programmatically copy the entire contents of the drawing area bounded by the client rectangle to the windows clipboard.

I've seen examples of copying images from specific controls to the clipboard; is there a simple way to do this for the whole client area?

Comment: Use the form's DrawToBitmap() method.  Then Clipboard.SetImage().  Pressing Alt+PrtSc is certainly easier.

Comment: Thanks Hans - this only copies the standard windows controls from the form to the bitmap without the custom graphics.  For some reason the graphics disappear from the form when I hit the alt key.  Sounds like I have more to learn about the graphics class.

Comment: Yes.  Never use CreateGraphics().